# PROBLEMA ULTIMA LINEA FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, agrupación, reporte

Buen dia
Tengo el siguiente problema en la generación de mi PDF (Tengo un salto de línea del ultimo valor de la ultima fila de cada grupo generado, anexo imagen), como puedo dejar alineado el valor de Monto otorgado en la línea que corresponde?

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Este es mi Codigo
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

```
$productTotal = null;
while($row = sybase_fetch_array($respuesta)) 
{
    //AGRUPACION POR ASESOR
    $breakAsesor = $row['fu_funcionario'] != $lastAsesor;
    if ($breakAsesor) 
    {

      $pdf->SetX(10);
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
      $pdf->Cell(20, 7, $row['fu_funcionario'] . ' - ' . $row['fu_nombre']);
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //AGRUPACION POR GRUPO
     $breakGrupo = $row['gr_grupo'] != $lastGrupo;
    if ($breakGrupo) 
    {
     /*if (isset($saldoTotal)) {
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 6);
        $pdf->Cell(90,7, USD . ' ' . number_format($saldoTotal, 2, ',', '.'), 0, 0, 'C');
      }*/
      if (isset($productTotal)) {
          $pdf->SetX(80);
          $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 6);
          $pdf->Cell(80,7, USD . ' ' . number_format($productTotal, 2, ',', '.'), 0, 0, 'C');
      }

      $pdf->Ln();
      $pdf->SetX(15);
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 6);
      $pdf->Cell(10, 7, $row['gr_grupo'] . ' - ' .$row['gr_nombre']);

      $pdf->SetX(70);
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 6);
      $pdf->Cell(10, 7,date("d/m/Y",strtotime($row['fecha_concesion'])),0,0,'C' );

      $pdf->SetX(90);
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 6);
      $pdf->Cell(10, 7,date("d/m/Y",strtotime($row['fecha_vencimiento'])),0,0,'C' );
      $saldoTotal =0;
      $productTotal =0;
    }
    
    //CORRIENDO LAS VARIABLES ACUMULATIVAS
    $lastAsesor = $row['fu_funcionario'];
    //$lastCliente=$row['codigo_cliente'];
    $lastGrupo = $row['gr_grupo'];
    $saldoTotal += ($row['capital_vencido']+$row['capital_por_vencer']);
    $productTotal += $row['desembolso'];
    
    
}//AQUI TERMINA DE EJECUTARSE EL WHILE PRINCIPAL

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Hola, podrias compartir el codigo como texto en vez de imagen, saludos!

Comment: En fpdf hay que procurar siempre hacer el salto de linea al final de la estructura del renglon y no al principio, de las dos maneras puede funcionar de forma correcta, pero de la segunda forma es menos propenso a errores, igual te sugiero añadir una celda de prueba utilizando `$x = $pdf->GetX(); $y = $pdf->GetY();` y añadas una celda para ubicarte donde pienses que esta el error exactamente, a veces se recorren las celdas y nos dan errores.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: De acuerdo voy a probar lo que me indicas, muchas gracias, al solucionar respondo si funciona.

Comment: @ruben en donde debo colocar ese GetX y GetY? antes del cierre del While? o en la agrupacion del monto? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: @Edominguez, ponlo despues de la ultima celda que te esta dando el error. si puedes compartir tu codigo completo donde incluyas el footer y el header seria de mas ayuda. 
Por cierto, en el codigo que compartiste, cual celda es la que arroja la que estas obteniendo problemas

Comment: Podrias tambien compartir la imagen que habias compartido antes?,